# How to print data shown on console in the html page in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, filter

I am trying to get filtered data in html page of Angular(frontend) using django rest framework(api) from django(backend). When I click program button for English in the department table, I want to view program of English department only in program table instead of all the programs. I get the filtered data via http request in console but not in the program page. I want to know how to get the filtered data from console to html page as I want to print the filtered data in program table.The code is given below:

#program.component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let program of programs">
    <td>{{program.programCode}}</td>
    <td>{{program.pro_name}}</td>
    <td>{{program.pro_shortForm}}</td>
    <td>{{program.DepartmentID}}</td>
    <td>{{program.pro_type}}</td>
  </tr>
```

#program.component.ts

```
id: number;
program: Program;

ngOnInit() : void {
  this.program = new Program();

  this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

  this.api.getOneProgram(this.id)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      this.program = data;
    }, error => console.log(error));
}

getPrograms = () => {
  this.api.getAllPrograms().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.programs = data;
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
}
```

In the console it shows:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {programCode: "119", pro_name: "B.A. (Hons.) in English", pro_shortForm: "ENG", pro_type: "honours", DepartmentID: "3"}
1: {programCode: "125", pro_name: "M.A. in English (Final)", pro_shortForm: "ENG(Final)", pro_type: "masters", DepartmentID: "3"}
2: {programCode: "126", pro_name: "M.A. in English (Preliminary & Final)", pro_shortForm: "ENG", pro_type: "masters", DepartmentID: "3"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: I get all the programs in the program table instead of filtered program shown in the console. I want to know how to get the filtered data in program table by parameter DepartmentID?

Answer (score 0):

```js
 public programs=[];
     this.api.getOneProgram(this.id)
        .subscribe(data => {
this.programs = data;
  console.log(this.programs)
     }, error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I already declared programs array and tried this answer. All the program data is shown in the program table instead of filtered data by parameter DepartmentID.

Answer (score 0):

You just misspelled the word programs.

Just change the spelling of this.program to this.programs.

```
console.log(data)
this.programs = data;
```